# What Is 51% Attack In Bitcoin? Can Crypto Mining Pools Invade A Majority Attack On Bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core

As the cryptocurrency mining is becoming less profitable for the small miners with rising electricity costs and a shrunken market due to big commercial miners pool, these pools pose a risk of a 51% attack to the cryptocurrency.

https://coingape.com/what-is-51-attack-in-bitcoin-blockchain/